# I need help with this rate of change problem

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative, volume

The solid shown in the figure below consists of a cylinder of the radius (r) and height (h)
and a hemispherical void of the radius (r). The dimensions at a given instant (t) are:
$$h(t)=3t^2+2;r(t)=8-\frac{t^2}{4}$$
Find the rate of change of the volume (V) and surface area (S) of the solid at $t = 4$
seconds. State whether (V) and (S) are increasing, decreasing or neither.
Note:

The volume of Sphere =$\frac{4}{3}πr^3$

$(Ans: \frac{dV}{dt} = - 1105.84 (Deceasing))$

[image: figure]

I tried this:
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{r}}*\frac{dr}{dt}$$

and said:
$$t=4$$
$$r(4)=4$$
$$\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{r}}=4πr^2;\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{-t}{2}$$

so:$$\frac{dV}{dt}=(4πr^2)*(\frac{-t}{2})$$

and the final result I get:

$$\frac{dV}{dt}=128π$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: @saulspatz edited it, take a look at it.

Comment: Try writing $V$ in terms of $t$ and then just taking $dV/dt$ directly.

Comment: did it, but it doesn't give the right answer!

Comment: You have not computed the volume of the solid in question.  You need to take the volume of the cylinder minus half the volume of the sphere.  You are just considering the volume of the sphere.

Comment: @saulspatz that's right

Answer (score 1):

**Volume-->**
$$V=\pi r^2h-\frac{2}{3}\pi r^3$$
$$V=\pi (8-\frac{t^2}{4})^2(3t^2+2)-\frac{2}{3}\pi (8-\frac{t^2}{4})^3$$
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\pi[(3t^2+2)*2(8-\frac{t^2}{4})*(\frac{-t}{2})+(8-\frac{t^2}{4})^2*6t]-[\frac{2}{3}\pi *3(8-\frac{t^2}{4})^2*(\frac{-t}{2})]$$
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\pi[\frac{19}{16}t^5-\frac{103}{2}t^3+432t]$$

At $t=4s$,
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\pi[\frac{19}{16}*4^5-\frac{103}{2}*4^3+432*4]=-352\pi\approx-1105.84$$

**Surface Area-->**
$$A=2\pi rh+3\pi r^2$$
$$A=2\pi(8-\frac{t^2}{4})(3t^2+2)+3\pi(8-\frac{t^2}{4})^2$$
$$\frac{dA}{dt}=\pi[2(3t^2+2)(\frac{-t}{2})+3*2(8-\frac{t^2}{4})(\frac{-t}{2})]$$
$$\frac{dA}{dt}=\pi[\frac{-9}{4}t^3-26t]$$

At $t=4s$,
$$\frac{dA}{dt}=\pi[\frac{-9}{4}*4^3-26*4]=-248\pi\approx-779.115$$